# sphinxcontrib.applehelp breaking sphinx builds with sphinx version less than 5.0

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils, apple-help

In early January 2024, all my sphinx builds failed, with this message when I did a make html:

The sphinxcontrib.applehelp extension used by this project needs at least Sphinx v5.0; it therefore cannot be built with this version.

Can someone explain what caused this apparent dependency on >= 5.0?  Is sphinxcontrib.applehelp part of the standard Sphinx distribution, and thus, does this situation mean Sphinx versions less than 5 are not usable?

What is the best workaround?   Is there a way to build without applehelp?

Obviously one can just bump up the Sphinx version, but other items (like, in my case, the sphinx_rtd_theme) do not always work with arbitrary Sphinx versions.

I tried using this combination:

```
    docutils==0.16
    sphinx==5.3
    sphinx_rtd_theme==1.0.0
```

This builds but produces HTML sites without working full-text search, which I suspect is a sphinx_rtd_theme problem.

"Working" means a couple of critical things:

- The usual RST markup for bullets produces proper bullets.
- The search bar displayed by sphinx_rtd_theme works properly (displaying hits for search terms).

Before this new dependency on ≥ 5.0 popped up, the combinations

```
sphinx==4.5, sphinx_rtd_theme==1.0.0
```

and

```
sphinx==3.5.4, sphinx_rtd_theme==1.0.0, and jinja2==3.0.3
```

were working for me in different builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Plone 6 Documentation. Until I can upgrade to Sphinx >=5, I have these pins in place.

```
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5
```

Sphinx does not do a good job of documenting what changes in these dependencies, and which versions of Sphinx are supported. So I used our GitHub Workflow history to find the [last successful build](https://github.com/plone/documentation/actions/runs/7426515614/job/20210378789#step:5:241), where I output all installed packages and versions. You could also use a `pip freeze` step to make it more legible.

Comment: I had to do the same thing, pinning obsolete versions of things like sphinxcontrib-applehelp.   I still would like to understand what caused that package to require Sphinx >= 5.0.  The trouble all started around January 12, 2024

Comment: I have no idea. I came up empty, looking for any relevant release notes in Sphinx. They omit when the `sphinxcontrib-*help` dependencies were upgraded. If this answer answered your question, would you please accept it?

Comment: @Trdiaz this is an archeology question and the change wasn't documented in the release notes nor in Sphinx's GitHub. My guess is that the cause of the change was a general internal code refactor of Sphinx core, like Sphinx changing from `os.path` to `pathlib` and it wasn't explicitly documented what extensions were impacted and why, because in that case it was all of them.

Comment: @Trdiaz I would advise you to upvote and accept Steve Piercy's answer because it's as good an answer as you're going to get on Stack Overflow. The only persons who could answer this more precisely would be the Sphinx maintainers.

Comment: This seems related: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinxcontrib-applehelp/pull/15.

Comment: Steve's answer was what worked for him and me.  This change was probably the worst calamity we have had with our Sphinx builds in several years, so I hope the people who did it had a reason.  The report above from mzjn does seem related.